# Docker Neo4j 5.15.0 community error when using public IP address

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, neo4j, connection

I need to access remotely to Neo4j running on a Docker container using the server's public IP address, but when I configure the IP address via parameters, the connection through http via 7474 port fails and neo4j.log shows these exceptions:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.bolt.protocol.common.connector.netty.SocketNettyConnector@2548fc01' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "bind(..) failed: Cannot assign requested address".
 
org.neo4j.configuration.helpers.PortBindException: An error occurred while trying to bind to the socket /<server_public_IP>:7687
 
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind(..) failed: Cannot assign requested address
```

The server is running on an AWS virtual server with these settings:

```
  Virtualization: amazon
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS              
          Kernel: Linux 6.2.0-1017-aws
    Architecture: arm64
```

I am using the latest [docker image for neo4j 5.15.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/neo4j/5.15.0/images/sha256-49209c959ae23185b7625d0f9185b59cb82269f2dfbeba266376afd1f55d4ed9?context=explore)

As instructed in the [Operations manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/configuration/), and [this post](https://community.neo4j.com/t/remote-neo4j-server-port-7474-connection-refused/30058) the command I am using to create and run the container with the neo4j image is:

```
sudo docker run -d 
    --name=neo4jdocker \
    --restart always \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/<my password> \
    --env NEO4J_server_memory_heap_initial__size=12288m \
    --env NEO4J_server_memory_heap_max__size=20480m \
    --env NEO4J_server_default__listen__address=0.0.0.0 \
    --env NEO4J_server_default__advertised_address=<server_public_IP> \
    --env NEO4J_server_bolt_enabled=true \
    --env NEO4J_server_bolt_tls__level=DISABLED \
    --env NEO4J_server_bolt_listen__address=0.0.0.0:7687 \
    --env NEO4J_server_bolt_advertised__address=<server_public_IP>:7687 \
    --env NEO4J_server_http_enabled=true \
    --env NEO4J_server_http_listen__address=0.0.0.0:7474 \
    --env NEO4J_server_http_advertised__address=<server_public_IP>:7474 \
    --env NEO4J_server_https_enabled=false \
    --volume=/home/ubuntu/path/data:/data \
    --volume=/home/ubuntu/path/import:/import \
    --volume=/home/ubuntu/path/logs:/logs \
    --volume=/home/ubuntu/path/plugins:/plugins \
    neo4j:5.15.0
```

Then the Neo4j finds something wrong and restarts each minute:

```
sudo docker ps
 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS     NAMES
2a641248b8d9   neo4j:5.15.0   "tini -g -- /startup…"   About a minute ago   Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago             neo4jdocker
```

On the other hand, when I create the container without the public IP configuration settings, everything works as expected locally at the server machine:

```
sudo docker run -d \
    --name=neo4jdocker \
    --restart always \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/<my password> \
    --env NEO4J_server_memory_heap_initial__size=12288m \
    --env NEO4J_server_memory_heap_max__size=20480m \
    --env NEO4J_server_default__listen__address=0.0.0.0 \
    --volume=/home/ubuntu/path/data:/data \
    --volume=/home/ubuntu/path/import:/import \
    --volume=/home/ubuntu/path/logs:/logs \
    --volume=/home/ubuntu/path/plugins:/plugins \
    neo4j:5.15.0
```

Docker reports everything ok:

```
sudo docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                            NAMES
f5432bafedd5   neo4j:5.15.0   "tini -g -- /startup…"   34 minutes ago   Up 34 minutes   0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp, :::7474->7474/tcp, 7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7687->7687/tcp, :::7687->7687/tcp   neo4jdocker
```

I even have access to the web interface:

```
curl http://localhost:7474

{
  "bolt_routing" : "neo4j://localhost:7687",
  "transaction" : "http://localhost:7474/db/{databaseName}/tx",
  "bolt_direct" : "bolt://localhost:7687",
 "neo4j_version" : "5.15.0",

  "neo4j_edition" : "community"
}
```

And obviously the ports appear to be listened by the docker container:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n
 
COMMAND       PID            USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 2179741            root    4u  IPv4 5668735      0t0  TCP *:7687 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2179747            root    4u  IPv6 5667661      0t0  TCP *:7687 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2179759            root    4u  IPv4 5670560      0t0  TCP *:7474 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2179766            root    4u  IPv6 5669470      0t0  TCP *:7474 (LISTEN)
```

And neo4j.log shows expected messages:

```
2023-12-27 15:30:10.305+0000 INFO  Starting...
2023-12-27 15:30:11.033+0000 INFO  This instance is ServerId{57946358} (57946358-4700-4f22-bb6f-9bf3d5559522)
2023-12-27 15:30:11.614+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 5.15.0 ========
2023-12-27 15:30:12.773+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687. 
2023-12-27 15:30:13.346+0000 INFO  HTTP enabled on 0.0.0.0:7474.
2023-12-27 15:30:13.347+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2023-12-27 15:30:13.349+0000 INFO  id: 0101D8AABC7A7290033198E46D8969889C893917A0BC961C751565FB9B130D40
2023-12-27 15:30:13.350+0000 INFO  name: system
2023-12-27 15:30:13.350+0000 INFO  creationDate: 2023-12-22T22:57:40.961Z
2023-12-27 15:30:13.350+0000 INFO  Started.
```

Can you please help me to identify what I did wrong? What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the default configuration, which I assumed would only work locally, and to my surprise it started responding to remote requests through the domain name.

```
    curl http://<server-domain>:7474
    
    {
      "bolt_routing" : "neo4j://<server-domain>:7687",
      "transaction" : "http://<server-domain>:7474/db/{databaseName}/tx",
      "bolt_direct" : "bolt://<server-domain>:7687",
      "neo4j_version" : "5.15.0",
      "neo4j_edition" : "community"
    }
```

So despite I did not set the specific server domain name nor the server's public IP address, Neo4j accepted connections through those.

Looking closer the Operation Manual documentation for the [server.default_listen_address setting](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/configuration-settings/#config_server.default_listen_address) it reads:

> To listen for connections on all interfaces, use "0.0.0.0".

So my interpretation is that changing the default value "localhost" to "0.0.0.0" in the configuration parameters was enough and all the other specific settings are redundant in this case:

```
    --env NEO4J_server_default__listen__address=0.0.0.0 \
```